# Reshaping a matrix in Matlab by selecting rows at a fixed distance

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-indexing

I have a matrix `D` in Matlab of dimension `(a*b)xc` with the following structure: suppose `a=3, b=4, c=3`

```
D=[1 1 10; 
   1 2 11; 
   1 3 17; 
   1 4 15; 
   2 1 68; 
   2 2 6; 
   2 3 15; 
   2 4 7; 
   3 1 5; 
   3 2 43; 
   3 3 0; 
   3 4 5];
```

The first column of `D` contains the numbers between `1` and `a` starting from `1` and increasing of `1` after `b` rows. The second column of `D` lists `[1 2 ... b]'` `a`-times.

I want to construct the matrix `E` of dimension `(a*b)xc` with the following structure

```
E=[1 1 10; 
   2 1 68; 
   3 1 5; 
   1 2 11;
   2 2 6; 
   3 2 43; 
   1 3 17; 
   2 3 15; 
   3 3 0; 
   1 4 15; 
   2 4 7; 
   3 4 5];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you simply want to sort the rows by the second column and are thinking too complicated:

```
E = sortrows(D,2)
```

Answer (score 1):

For a general case when the input data is not already sorted, an approach based on `reshape` and `permute` would be suited -

```
E = reshape(permute(reshape(D,b,size(D,1)/b,[]),[2 1 3]),size(D))
```